# Dataframe to key/value Dict as tuple/object format

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following pandas df:

```
id1 id2 f1 f2 f3
  1   1  a  b  c
  1   2  d  e  f
```

The result I would like is:

```
{
    (1, 1): {"f1": "a", "f2": "b", "f3": "c"},
    (1, 2): {"f1": "d", "f2": "e", "f3": "f"}
}
```

I managed to get somewhere with

```
df.set_index(['id1', 'id2'])['f1'].to_dist()
```

but it only solves the `key` part of the problem and not the `value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.to_dict` with `orient=index`:

```
df.set_index(['id1','id2']).to_dict('index')
```

> index’ : dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

---

```
{(1, 1): {'f1': 'a', 'f2': 'b', 'f3': 'c'},
 (1, 2): {'f1': 'd', 'f2': 'e', 'f3': 'f'}}
```